# Select from a view taking a lot of time

Tags: view, query-optimization, sql-server-2014

I have created a view using below tables. This view takes a lot of time for returning output. I am using this view with other table by left join. Is there any way to increase the performance of below view?

DDL commands:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCT_TEXT]
(
    [Product] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Format] [nvarchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [Text_Code] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [F_Date_Stamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [DATA_CODE] [nvarchar](8) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Staging_T_PROD_TEXT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Product] ASC,
    [Format] ASC,
    [Text_Code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].PHRASE_LINK]
(
    [LINK_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PHRASE_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DATA_CODE] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [TEXT_CODE] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Staging_T_PHRASE_LINKAGE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LINK_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PHRASE_TRANSLATIONS](
    [F_TRANSLATION_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [F_PHRASE_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [F_LANGUAGE] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [F_PHRASE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_PHRASE_TRANSLATIONS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [F_TRANSLATION_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROD_ALIAS_TEXT]
(
    [ALIAS] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FORMAT] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [DATA_CODE] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [TEXT_CODE] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PROD_ALIAS_TEXT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [F_ALIAS] ASC,
    [F_FORMAT] ASC,
    [F_TEXT_CODE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Non-clustered index details for these tables:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PROD_TEXT ON PRODUCT_TEXT (TEXT_CODE, PRODUCT)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PROD_TEXT_1 ON PROD_TEXT (DATA_CODE, PRODUCT)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PHRASE_LINK ON PHRASE_LINK (TEXT_CODE)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PHRASE_Translations ON PHRASE_transaltions(phrase_id)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PHRASE_Translations_LANG ON PHRASE_transaltions(LANGUAGE)
```

View definition:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MANU_TEST] 
AS
    SELECT 
        PT.PRODUCT AS PRODUCT, PT.TEXT_CODE AS TEXT_CODE, 
        PHT.PHRASE AS F_PHRASE 
    FROM 
        PRODUCT_TEXT PT
    LEFT JOIN 
        PHRASE_LINK PHL ON PT.TEXT_CODE = PHL.TEXT_CODE
    INNER JOIN 
        PHRASE_TRANSLATIONS PHT ON PHL.PHRASE_ID = PHT.PHRASE_ID
    WHERE 
        PT.DATA_CODE = 'MANU' AND PHT.LANGUAGE = 'EN'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        PT.F_ALIAS AS PRODUCT, PT.TEXT_CODE AS TEXT_CODE, 
        PHT.PHRASE AS F_PHRASE 
    FROM 
        PROD_ALIAS_TEXT PT
    LEFT JOIN 
        PHRASE_LINK PHL ON PT.TEXT_CODE = PHL.TEXT_CODE
    INNER JOIN 
        PHRASE_TRANSLATIONS PHT ON PHL.PHRASE_ID = PHT.PHRASE_ID
    WHERE 
        PT.DATA_CODE = 'MANU' AND PHT.LANGUAGE = 'EN'
```

This view takes a lot of time to return output.

Comment: Have you checked an actual **execution plan** for a `SELECT` on this view? What does it tell you?

Comment: yes.i checked the execution plan.how can i post the execution plan here?

Comment: For example in [Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: plan url https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkmoXhVzE

Comment: Why split out the product and alias as two products? It seems like you are doing twice the work here. What's your `MAXDOP` setting?

Comment: maxdop setting is 0.i am selecting product from PRODUCT_TEXT table and alias from another table PROD_ALIAS_TEXT.